# 'subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector' error

Tags: c

I've read questions about similar problems, but **2D** or **dynamic** arrays' problems has been solved there. (There are pointers, but I'd like to do it without them.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int interseq ( int, int ); // interval sequence

int main()
{
    int arr[100] = { 75, 47, 64, 45, 67, 51, 55, 36, 63, 30,
                     39, 58, 55, 67, 70, 44, 46, 51, 51, 61,
                     50, 54, 49, 51, 52, 54, 64, 68, 45, 40,
                     48, 60, 55, 37, 36, 13, 62, 53, 37, 53,
                     52, 49, 37, 54, 69, 44, 53, 58, 77, 46,

                     44, 63, 57, 64, 28, 46, 50, 57, 42, 72,
                     12, 69, 52, 53, 77, 50, 45, 49, 49, 46,
                     28, 40, 65, 25, 45, 45, 62, 28, 39, 69,
                     52, 57, 39, 73, 37, 46, 38, 65, 49, 58,
                     63, 30, 51, 48, 47, 56, 48, 41, 30, 54 };

    printf("%d", interseq ( arr, diagArr) );

    return 0;
} 

/* User's function. Description: 'farr' is 'arr' and so on..  */
int interseq ( int farr, int fdiagArr)
{
   int min, i;

   for ( i = 0; i < 100; i++ )    // Finding the 'min' element.
      if ( farr[i+1] < farr[i] )  // there are 2 errors 
          min = farr[i];          // there is 1 error 
      else
          min = farr[i+1];        // there is 1 error 

return 1;
}
```

**The errors are the same:**

```
error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
```

Comment: You should present the actual code. The variable `fdiagArr` isn't defined and that's the first error to look at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make those into pointers:

```
int interseq(int *farr, int *fdiagArr)
                 ^          ^
```

I can't see what `diagArr` is in your code so that part is speculation.

---

As simonc points in the comments, when `i = 99`, `farr[i+1]` will be illegal. You should stop earlier or change your algorithm.

Comment: +1.  Should also exit the loop in `interseq` on `i<99` to avoid reading beyond the end of the array.

Comment: That helped me. But there is `warning: variable 'min' set but not used`. 
It is being used! (min = ...)
Why?

Comment: @Genuine.Zealot You assign to it but don't do anything (else) with it.

Comment: @duDE No it's not. Actually the standard C library doesn't even provide a `min` function.

Comment: Q: Are you sure you're using C ? ___  A: I'm using IDE Code::Blocks. I've created a new project 'C'. (main.c)  

___ What is wrong?

Comment: @Genuine.Zealot Sorry, I had never seen that bit in gcc's error messages.

Comment: Please, tell me: what is more [easy\faster\more optimized] using `*farr` or `farr[]` ?   ---> It is very important.

Comment: @Genuine.Zealot In this context they are **completely** identical. But only in this context. In this context `int farr[1000]` is *also* completely equivalent to `int *farr` or `int farr[]`.

Comment: The techers make all students to write simple, light, easy-to-read, optimized code. That's why I've asked abuot it. 
____________Thanks! The problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//int interseq ( int farr, int fdiagArr)
int interseq ( int farr[], int fdiagArr[])
```